# How can I add Dynamic Field to Wordpress Contact Form 7?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have installed a plugin to add a Conditional Field based on the questions the user answers. However in the dynamic field I have a JS script that loads a appointment widget from SquareUp. The problem is when the JS script provided by SquareUp detects the area is not big enough for the appointments widget it converts into a button that the user can click and it goes to a new page.

Anyone know how I can load this JS script into the Conditional Fields area properly?

Comment: possible load the SquareUp into a popup overlay div and make it big enough to accommodate it? when the user has finished interacting with it, you can close the popup to return to the underlying form?

Comment: I want to put it on the page and not in a pop up which would make it a little less seo friendly

Comment: then you'll need to make enough space on the page.  The logic for script rendering is controlled by SquareUp, so you don't have any other alternatives

Comment: Would you happen to know why the JS script is duplicating itself? The JS script just loads an iframe to an appointment widget. However I only put the JS script on the page once but it duplicates itself causing multiple widgets to show up in the div.

Comment: By the way thank you for taking your time to help me here

Comment: it duplicates itself?  You haven't mentioned anything of the sort in your question.  Your issue was about the script not displaying as a button instead of a widget when the space is limited.  Without more details of your code/form it not possible to say.